# Is this a fairly decent description for a post-apocalyptic fiction story?

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, culture, environment, post-apocalypse

Okay so the story takes place up in the northern hemisphere around glaciers and polar bears and all that good stuff, its main character is named Xavior and he is a good human adapted to the radioactive polar environment. Before the war and all of this happened genetic engineering was booming and some people made a controversial move towards editing their genomes to make them more specialized.

> Xavior's genetic altering consists of having a slow-growing thick exoskeleton-like armor around his body to protect him against radiation and wildlife; it is very hard to break. He also has a very good immune system a lot like that of bats, a fast metabolism because he cannot store much fat from his shell restrictions, high iodine levels, and a very good set if kidneys to get rid of almost all his bodily impurities so he doesn't need to sweat them out. He is born with highly developed muscles so he can move around with his exoskeleton and the exoskeleton can take a lot of damage, even machine gun fire.
>
> He has a pet woolly mammoth because in the past they were revived through cloning and some were put in the while others were trained to use to make money for the extinct animal revival program. His mammoth looks a lot like a giant baby mammoth and helps raise morale and carries his supplies for him as he travels around.
>
> From all the radiation most of the survivors have mutated and the fertile ones bred; the most beneficial mutations became common so the humans look a bit weirder. Things are much simpler now and reflect the early Dark Ages. The people look back at the ancient society like a Utopia and feel bad about where they are now, and to remove that depression they feed their reindeer mushrooms then drink the urine as a drug.
>
> They eat a lot of meat and bread and any other food they can find up north, in particular, they love their salmon. It's really cloudy and cold as the average lowest is 0F and the average highest is 57F. Most of the people work in a feudal-like system with a lot of reindeer farming
>
> Xavior is a merchant who goes to the wrecked old cities and brings back these items from them as relics and sells them for food and other supplies. He scavenges for food leftovers and eats a lot of honey.

So does this seem like a sound post-apocalyptic setting or is it inaccurate and needs work?

Comment: The idea as a whole is pretty ok, i have gripes with them taking mushrooms and drinking pee and anti-depressants or some sort of escape drug. I'm all getting high no issue there. Also, does it serve a bigger purpose for plot or society? P.S. Rek beat me to the edit haha

Comment: It's what people used to do up north back in the day and it does eventually serve in the plot I try to make every detail serve in it

Comment: I dont know much about the northen stuff, seems pretty good otherwise to me. Good luck with it all, a wanderer with a mammoth sounds nice.

Comment: Thx man appreciate it

Comment: I switched from science based to reality check, because 1) it is a reality check, 2) good reality check should be science compliant enough and 3) didn't want to remove any other tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few points to take care of:

> a slow growing thick exoskeleton-like armor around his body

This strongly limits mobility, as the joints will have less freedom of movement

> a fast metabolism because he cannot store much fat from his shell restrictions

Metabolism is used to produce energy for the body, not to burn fats (that's a consequence). Sloths are no fatter than mice, though having a slower metabolism. Living in the cold north a higher metabolism may be needed to keep the body warm (provided the intake is adequate)

> high iodine levels

Why? Iodine pills are used to saturate the thyroid and protect it from the intake of radioactive iodine from the environment. Once it is saturated you don't need to keep the high level. You just want to be sure your iodine intake is non radioactive.

> a very good set if kidneys to get rid of almost all his bodily
>   impurities so he doesn't need to sweat them out

Sweating is used mostly for controlling the body temperature. We humans are among the few sweating mammals, some said because we have evolved for endurance and run. Being triggered by rising body temperatures, sweating is not a wise way to systematically remove toxins from the body (hey, let's take a run to get rid of some urea)

Comment: Last quote is about kidneys and you talk about sweat. Something went wrong with last edit?

Comment: @Mołot, thanks for pointing it out, I forgot the last part of the quote which involves sweating. Now it should make sense

Comment: Okay thx but I have has doctors tell me sweat also removes toxins

Comment: @user45751 yes, it does, but only insignificant part of these toxins because our kidneys are already good enough for us to not *need* sweating for toxin removal.

Comment: Okay then thx buddy